# How do I map number ranges to each other?

Tags: ruby, numbers

How can I map two opposing numbers ranges to each other?

I have one range with three numbers: `1, 2, 3` (and any potential decimals).

I'd like to roughly map that on a range of 1000 to 0.

So, `1 = 1000`, `2 = 500`, `3 = 0`.

Ultimately, I want to take a number like 1.68 and figure out where on that 1000-0 scale it'd match up.

Comment: Could you elaborate better? Maybe explain why you want to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_%28paranormal%29)!

Assuming you want a linear mapping from your first range (1-3) to your second (1000-0, descending), this will be your function:

```
y = (3 - x) / 2 * 1000
```

where `x` is the input (`1 <= x <= 3`) and `y` is the output (`0 <= y <= 1000`).

This can be generalized to different ranges as needed.

Patent pending.

Comment: What role is 2 playing in the original sequence 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @sawa It's a rating scale. 1 = negative, 2 = neutral, 3 = positive.